# VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE intent with the screen off

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity with an intent-filter for capturing long presses on headphones (voice search), but it only works when the screen is on

I already tried moving the intent filter to a service, but it never fired (my guess is it must be on an activity so the user gets a visual cue?).

Here is my activity declaration from my manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.LongPressActivity">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.speech.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.speech.action.VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I'm searching informations about that too. I don't understand how the VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE works and can't find documentation about it ...